# Calculate profit or loss based on some specific condition

Tags: sql-server

I want to make a query that calculate profit if sale price is greater than cost price and calculate loss when cost price is greater than sale price. I have separate columns for sale price and cost price in the same table.

```
saleprice   costprice   profit   loss
   5           6          0       1
  10           5          5       0
```

How can I achieve this functionality?Any help will be appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT *
  ,CASE WHEN costprice > saleprice THEN costprice - saleprice ELSE 0 END as loss
  ,CASE WHEN saleprice > costprice THEN saleprice - costprice ELSE 0 END as profit
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce1fc8f6f38b0e3e8b8b9b21f87767ac)**